# Passing variables in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm running into a wall passing a variable as a param to a component in Ember.

In one template, I'm looping through Ember Data model "user" like so:

```
{{#each user in users}}
  {{person-entry user=user status=??}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm trying to pass the status element of the user. If I put {{user.status}} above the {{person-entry}} tag, it displays the correct result on the page. However, if I pass it as the value of status, it's undefined. Trying to access if from the user param also returns undefined.

When I inspect the store in the Ember console, the data is there as well.

How can I pass this value and have access to it in the component? What am I missing?

*Additional:* If I put {{user.status}} in the template for {{person-entry}}, it also displays correctly.

UPDATE:

Additional code, as requested...
     User model

```
   import DS from 'ember-data';

   var attr = DS.attr;

   export default DS.Model.extend({
del: attr(),
status: attr(),
source: attr(),
ppoem_reader_number: attr(),
first_name: attr(),
last_name: attr(),
title: attr(),
job_duty: attr(),
email: attr(),
direct_phone: attr(),
company: DS.belongsTo('company')
 });
```

Component "person-entry"

```
 import Ember from 'ember';


  export default Ember.Component.extend({
    editStatus: '', 
    status: '',
    showEdit: false,
    statusOk: Ember.computed.equal('editStatus', 'OK'),
    statusDelete: Ember.computed.equal('editStatus', 'DELETE'),
    statusOpen: Ember.computed.equal('editStatus', ''),
    didInsertElement: function() {
      this.set('status', this.get('status'));
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using to assign `user.status` to `status`, and also the way you reference it from within the component.

Comment: maybe `user.status` is a promise?

Comment: @andrusieczko I thought that, too. I tried putting a timeout in to delay requesting it, but no dice.

Comment: @torazaburo 

It looks like {{person-entry status=user.status}}. I've also tried just {{person-entry status=status}} to no avail. 

Inside the component, I'm attempting to request it with this.get('status').

Comment: can we see more code? `person-entry` component for example? the definition of `user` model might be helpful as well

Comment: @andrusieczko please see updates to original question. thanks!

Comment: hmm, except the fact that you don't have to explicitly set it that way: `didInsertElement: function() { this.set('status', this.get('status')); }`, it should work...

Comment: That's what I thought too. But it returns undefined in either case. Yet it shows up if I call it via handlebars.

Comment: I understand, that you pass it as `{{person-entry status=user.status}}` and in the component `console.log(this.get('status')` gives you `undefined`?

Comment: Correct. I've also tried this.get('user.status') and this.get('user').get('status') just to see if I was somehow forgetting the syntax.

Comment: how do you get your `user` model (instance) and where?

Comment: The model is loaded from the route that person-entry is in via an api call.

Comment: can I see the corresponding parts of code in `person-entry` controller and route?

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone right now, about 1am here. The route literally is model:function(params) { return this.store.find('user', params.company_id); }    Users is referenced by id in the company model (hasMany) and async loads, based on those ids. There is no controller for person-entry, just the component definition and its template.

Comment: then it is probably something with promises / wrong `users` object.. I don't know; gotta see the real code of the controllers/routes :)

Comment: I'll try to post in the morning. Thanks for the help.